# Closed rectangle contained in set that does not have measure zero.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was doing some analysis when it occurred to me that if I knew the answer to the following question many of the exercises would be simpler. However, I haven't been able to make much headway. Any help will be appreciated.

**Question:**
If I have a set $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $S$ is not of measure 0, is it always true that there exists some closed rectangle $C$ such that $C \subseteq S$?

Comment: The answer is no, $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ being an example (as indicated in the answers).  But there are some important instances where the answer is true that are helpful to keep in mind.  For instance, the set on which a continuous function is positive (or negative) has positive measure, being that it contains a $k$-cell (rectangle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Think of $\mathbb R \backslash \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Can't believe I missed this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample:  $[0,1]-\mathbb{Q}$  has a non zero measure, yet it does not contain an interval.

Comment: Doesn't it contain $]1/3, 2/3[$?

Comment: You are certainly right

Comment: I think my example is better.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva Your now corrected answer looks OK.

Comment: @Peter : I read "measure zero" instead of "non-zero measure" the first time, hence the wrong answer. Now it's fine.

Comment: @PatrickDasilva Yyes your example is better. By the way I edited my answer before looking at yours